# Are Https-only cookies vulnerable to CSRF attacks?

Tags: cookies, csrf

Given the hypothetical situation:

1. A user logs into his banking website
2. The server returns a Http-only cookie containing the user's id, encrypted.
3. On each request (such as when transferring funds), the server decrypts and checks the id.

No CSRF tokens are generated on any of the forms, and request validation is based on the encrypted id.

Is a CSRF attack possible under this scenario?  If so, how would it work?

Comment: To really understand this, I'd encourage you to download a deliberately vulnerable app, like WebGoat, and try a CSRF exploit. If you're already tech-savvy this isn't too hard, and practical experience is the best kind of understanding.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, CSRF is still possible, and it works the same as CSRF would normally work.

The HTTP-only flag is useful for protected a cookie from an XSS attack which injects JavaScript to try to read the cookie and send it back to the attacker. For protecting against CSRF attacks, it is completely useless.

Comment: Browsers stop cookies from being sent from a different domain, so how would a different domain send the HTTP-only cookie?

Comment: @NathanMerrill The other domain has a separate set of cookie which the browsers sends to it. The attacker doesn't need to know what the are, the browser sends them automatically.

Comment: So, if a form on `attackerwebsite.com` sends a POST request to `mybank.com`, the browser will attach all of the `mybank.com` cookies with it?

Comment: @NathanMerrill Yep.

Comment: Another question:  What's to stop malicious JS to request the page with the form on it, and parsing out the csrf token?

Comment: @NathanMerrill Same-Origin Policy. Provided there are no XSS vulnerabilities, and the token is unique per-client, this would not be possible.